# How to use arm template deployment IPAddress output a powershell target machine ip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to deploy a vm using ARM template and use the IP of the machine as powershell target machine Ip to run scripts inside the VM that got deployed.

I added output variable in arm template which is giving the Ip address of the machine that is getting deployed.

```
"outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    },
    "PublicIPAddress": {
         "type": "string",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIpAddressName')).ipAddress]"
    }
}
```

**I am capturing that Ip as Deployment Output like this** [image]

**And in the powershell task i am able to print that Ip address like this**

[image]

**But when i use the same as target machine IP like this it is saying that hostname cannot be parsed**
[image]

**I am attaching the outputs that i am getting here**

[image]

[image]

Can Someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT i fixed it in the same approach you suggested.. 
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Deployment Output value cannot be referenced in the task `PowerShell on target machines`.

Please try setting the Deployment Output to an environment [variable in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) via powershell task. See below:

Add a powershell task to run below scripts to set the Deployment Output to variable `IpAddress`: See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3#deployment-outputs).

```
$var=ConvertFrom-Json '$(ArmOutput)'
$value=$var.PublicIPAddress.value
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IpAddress;]$value"
```

[image]

In the task `PowerShell on target machines`, you can reference the variable `IpAddress` created in above powershell task:

[image]